# Install not up to date dependency on angular project

Tags: angular, npm

Is it risky to use a library whose version of angular is older than the project? Is it recommended to use `npm i --force` in these cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a library with a different version of Angular might lead unexpected behaviour or simply non-working code, since certain (peer-)dependencies might be incompatible and involve breaking changes.

The `npm i --force` is used to fetch the package from remote and ignore the cache on disk.
See the official [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install)